# Send POST json data to an url with POSTMAN not working

Tags: postman

I have python code wrote here: https://repl.it/@AndreiCiobnic/MixedWealthyGnuassembler

I'm trying to (re)write in Postman to make a POST request to that url.

I put like:

[image: postman]

But I got error response from that server.

[image: error]

How to send the data json in Postman ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: See updated post. Just simple error text